# When is $Pn^2-2an+\frac{a^2-k}{P}$ , with $P$ Prime, $k=a^2 mod P$, a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-numbers

It is easy to show that the following problems are equivalent.

a.  When is $Pn^2-2an+\frac{a^2-k}{P}$ , with $P$ Prime, $k=a^2 mod P$, and $n$ any integer, a square?

and

b.  When is $X^2-PY^2=k$ solvable in integers?

So, any suggestions on problem a ?  How fast would an algorithm used to compute this run ?

Comment: I don't follow.  Problems like Problem a are solved precisely by rewriting them as Pell's equations whenever possible.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article on Pell's equation.  There is even some discussion of runtime for classical and quantum computers.

Comment: I think the questioner is asking which numbers are norms in $Z[\sqrt P]$ which is different from Pell's equation. E.g., if you ask when you can solve this for primes $k$, then the question is which rational prime ideals split or ramify into principal ideals in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)$. Pell's equation asks how to find the units.